# Cosa significa "effettato" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Ero lì ogni sera in prima fila, a godermi la vista di quel corpo grande e caldo che si muoveva seminudo sotto le luci **effettate**, esposto all'ammirazione di tutti eppure mio, tutto mio.

Non capisco il significato dell'aggettivo "effettato" in questo brano: le definizioni che ho trovato in alcuni dizionari fanno tutte riferimento allo sport. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Credo** che Gassman stia usando un termine che io suppongo essere entrato nel gergo teatrale come calco dall'inglese "effect lighting" (che penso si possa rendere con "illuminazione d'atmosfera"?) e si riferisce ad una [illuminazione](http://www.osram.com/osram_com/applications/effect-lighting/) progettata per rendere una particolare "atmosfera", attraverso colori, contrasti, sfumature, chiaroscuri e a volte anche modifiche nel tempo (es. un colore che sfuma gradualmente in un altro).

"Effettato" normalmente significa "che ha ricevuto un effetto" ma con riferimento, come ha precisato DaG, all'effetto Magnus.

Qui probabilmente le luci erano dirette in modo da sottolineare il "numero" dell'artista.

Answer (score 1):

Il termine viene usato principalmente in campo sportivo:

> - (SPORT Di colpo, tiro, traiettoria,) a effetto, eseguito con effetto: *un tiro imprendibile perché effettato.*

Hoepli

- Nel contesto del brano penso si riferisca alla direzione, alla traiettoria delle luci, predisposte per creare un effetto di maggiore visibilità, di migliore esposizione allo sguardo degli altri.

Comment: Per chiarire, in un tiro in cui si dà un effetto a una palla, le si imprime una rotazione in modo che per [effetto Magnus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) cambino le proprietà aerodinamiche della palla, e quindi per esempio percorra unon più una normale parabola (a meno della resistenza dell'aria), ma una curva non piana. Non so se qui Gassman si riferisse metaforicamente a questo o avesse in mente altri effetti, come luci colorate o lampeggianti o chissà che.

Comment: Josh61: penso che, se inserissi il contenuto del commento di @DaG nel tuo post, sarebbe una buona risposta.

Comment: Cioè, la tua ipotesi è una possibile spiegazione, ma ci sono altri effetti delle luci a cui l'aggettivo "effettato" si potrebbe anche riferire.

Comment: Charo - Sì, ci stiamo muovendo  nel campo delle ipotesi, ma penso che sia più corretto se @DaG posta una sua risposta.