# Inserimento di una proposizione condizionale in una frase con "penso che": come si deve cambiare il tempo verbale?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

Ho avuto questo dubbio mentre scrivevo un commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/7108). So che in una proposizione subordinata dipendente del verbo "pensare" per esprimere un'opinione, in genere si deve usare il congiuntivo. Per esempio:

> Penso che sia una buona risposta.

Il mio dubbio è su come si deve trasformare il tempo verbale in questa frase se voglio introdurre una proposizione per indicare una condizione dalla quale dipende il fatto che io pensi che la risposta sia buona. Nel commento che ho scritto nel post, ho usato il congiuntivo imperfetto nella condizionale (ipotesi possibile nel futuro) e il condizionale presente invece del congiuntivo presente nella proposizione reggente, ma non sono sicura che questo sia corretto:

> Penso che, se inserissi il contenuto del commento di @DaG nel tuo post, sarebbe una buona risposta.

Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: (Penso che) se (tu) ***inserissi*** il commento, la risposta ***sarebbe*** buona.

Comment: @Josh61: Non capisco cosa vuoi dire.

Comment: ho scritto la frase correttamente, la tua a me sembra sgrammaticata, o quantomeno non mi suona bene.

Comment: L'eventualità nel futuro si esprime con il condizionale, se c'è una dipendenza da un'azione incerta: "penso che sarà una buona risposta, quando avrai aggiunto il commento” (certezza che il commento sarà aggiunto); “penso che sarebbe (diventerebbe) una buona risposta, se DaG aggiungesse il commento” (dipendenza da volontà altrui).

Answer (score 2):

La frase:

> Penso che, se inserissi il contenuto del commento di @DaG nel tuo
> post, sarebbe una buona risposta.

è corretta. Un'alternativa, per preservare la struttura ***penso che** + **congiuntivo***, potrebbe essere:

> Penso che la tua sia una buona risposta, a patto che tu inserisca il contenuto del commento di @DaG nel tuo post.

Seppure la costruzione risulti un po' più contorta in questo caso, e stilisticamente non vedo perché ci si dovrebbe intestardire nell'utilizzare i due congiuntivi.

Per rispondere alla tua domanda, non mi avventuro in spiegazioni che fanno uso di "manualistica" grammaticale (delle quali non sarei capace), ma mi limito a fornire un semplice criterio pratico per la costruzioni di simili frasi.

"Penso che..." può essere vista come una reggente, dalla quale possono diramarsi altre strutture.

**1º caso** - Se "penso che..." regge una singola frase **al presente**, come nel caso di  "*penso che tu sia troppo curioso*", il congiuntivo è necessario per tener conto dell'*incertezza* intrinseca nel verbo *pensare*.

**2º caso** - Se invece la struttura che segue è più complessa, come nel caso di una frase **al futuro**, di un periodo ipotetico o di una subordinata temporale con sotto-strutture, "penso che..." rimane come reggente, ma tutto il resto viene coniugato normalmente.

Chiaramente, espressioni come "credo che...", "sono certo che..." e simili possono essere trattate allo stesso modo.

Esempi di questo secondo caso:

> Penso che Clara si stupirà quando vedrà cosa la aspetta.
>
> Penso che martedì prossimo andremo al cinema.
>
> Penso che sarebbe giusto fermarsi qui, se ci fosse una tempesta.
>
> Penso che, se Dio vorrà, arriveremo sani e salvi.

Nel primo caso:

> Penso che la situazione non sia delle migliori.

Comment: Non pretendo essere esperta ma questa ultima risposta mi sembra ottima. Ho notato nella mie letture che quando la seconda struttura indica un atto certo nel futuro si usa il tempo futuro invece del solito congiuntivo. Siccome l'italiano non è la mia lingua materna volevo rassicurarmi che quel uso fosse corretto. La risposta di usumdelphini mi da tutta la rassicurazione di cui ho bisogno. Grazie mille!

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Annunziat'F! Penso che il tuo post sia più un commento alla risposta di usumdelphini che una vera risposta.

Answer (score 0):

## Condizionale

Il condizionale è un modo verbale che indica fatti che possono avverarsi solo a determinate condizioni:

1. mangerei ---- verbo al condizionale
2. ----- se avessi fame ----la condizione necessaria allo svolgimento dell’azione
3. farei ---verbo al condizionale ----
4. una passeggiata se avessi tempo --- condizione necessaria allo
   svolgimento dell’azione

Il modo condizionale ha due tempi:

> presente o semplice: si forma con il verbo principale 
>   
>   passato o composto: si forma unendo l’ausiliare essere o avere + verbo

### QUANDO SI USA IL CONDIZIONALE PRESENTE?

Nel presente o nel futuro per:

1. Fare una richiesta in modo gentile:
   mi daresti un fazzoletto?; potrei avere un po’ di zucchero?

   Esprimere un desiderio o un’intenzione:
   mi piacerebbe tanto venire in vacanza con voi.

   Esprimere un dubbio: 
   non so se riuscirei a fargli cambiare idea; riferire una notizia non

   Confermata o di cui non si è certi
   secondo il meteo domani sarebbe una giornata piovosa

   Per esprimere un’opinione personale, dare un un consiglio o un ordine:
   secondo me dovresti studiare di più

Poiché il condizionale presente si forma dalla radice del futuro, i verbi della prima coniugazione trasformano la "a" dell'infinito in "e" e i verbi che sono irregolari nel futuro lo sono anche nel condizionale presente . Guarda qui un esempio con il verbo `parlare`: 
PARLARE

1. Io parlerei
2. Tu parleresti
3. Lui/Lei parlerebbe
4. Noi parleremmo
5. Voi parlereste
6. Loro parlerebbero

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Scusa, ma non capisco niente di quello che dici.

Comment: Ho modificato la risposta e l'ho fatta un po' più dettagliata. Dimmi se ora hai capito

Comment: Scusa, ma il tuo post non è una risposta alla mia domanda.

Comment: Anch'io non vedo nessun nesso fra questo bignami sul condizionale e la domanda.